# define colors for variable in php

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to echo a variable in a red color in one part of my web application, but what i have printed is this:

```
<div style="Color:red">$output</div>
```

This my code:

```
if($username_exist) {
  $output= "Username taken";
  echo "<div style=\"color: red;\">$variable</div>";
}else{
  echo('available');
}
```

Thanks

Comment: I just have checked...Its working fine..$variable must be $output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To me it looks as if nothing will get printed assuming **$variable** is not defined anywhere else.
Try using $output as the variable:

```
if($username_exist) {
  $output= "Username taken";
  echo "<div style=\"color: red;\">".$output."</div>";
}else{
  echo('available');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[demo](https://eval.in/238735)

```
if ($username_exist) {
    $output = "Username taken";
    $message = "<div style=\"color: red;\">$output</div>";
} else {
    $output = "available";
    $message = "<div style=\"color: green;\">$output</div>";
}

echo $message;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the < div > and replace it with < font >. Also use single quotes when outputting a HTML element so you can easily add the attributes.

```
if($username_exist) {
   $output= "Username taken";
   echo '<font color="red">' . $variable . '</font>';
}else{
   echo('available');
}
```